# No Boxing Conversion for two type parameters shared Parent and Child

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, boxing

I get the following error (VSC#2010 Express) on the declaration of GetChild method...

Error   1   The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method '...Child'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to '...IParent'.

```
public interface IParent<T, Id>
{
    Child<T, Id> GetChild();
}

public class Child<T, Id> where T : IParent<T, Id>
{
    public T Parent;
}
```

I want any class to inherit IParent, and for each such class to construct a member instance of Child.

T is the class inheriting IParent, and Id is an enum in the parent scope of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try constraining type T in the interface as well.

```
public interface IParent<T, Id> where T : IParent<T, Id>
{
    Child<T, Id> GetChild();
}

public class Child<T, Id> where T : IParent<T, Id>
{
    public T Parent;

    public Child<T, Id> GetChild()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Np. If the answer is sufficient, please marked as answered. Thanks.