# There is no boxing or type parameter conversion

Tags: c#, list, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm getting the following error:

> Error 1   The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method 'ClassLibrary1.A'. There is no boxing or
>   type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'ClassLibrary1.ALayer'.

I'm trying to apply Generics to achieve a dynamic polymorphism with Lists and inheritance. I have the following class structure:

```
public abstract class ALayer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class A<T> where T: ALayer
{
    public List<T> Layers;
}
```

I'm getting the error in the declaration of the Middle class

```
public abstract class Middle<T>:A<T>
{
    public int middleAttr { get; set; }
}
```

This is my third layer of classes where I wanto to get the dynamic polymorphism

```
public class BLayer : ALayer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class B:Middle<BLayer>
{
    public B() {
        this.Layers = new List<BLayer>();
    }
}
```

What is this error?

Any help will be much appreciated

**Answer**
I had to explicitly name the constraint

```
public abstract class Middle<T>:A<T> where T: ALayer
{
    public int middleAttr { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How can `Middle` be sure that `T` satisfies the type constraint of `A`? Resharper actually offers you the solution in this case if you use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No Boxing Conversion for two type parameters shared Parent and Child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543043/no-boxing-conversion-for-two-type-parameters-shared-parent-and-child)

Comment: Thank you @chris, I had to explicitly name the Middle constraint. I edited my question.

Comment: @svillalta Please convert the last part of your question to an actual answer.

Answer (score 7):

I had to explicitly name the constraint on the Middle class

```
public abstract class Middle<T>:A<T> where T: ALayer
{
    public int middleAttr { get; set; }
}
```